# Why is my unwind segue crashing my app?

Tags: ios, swift, segue, unwind-segue

I am trying to create an unwind segue that takes me back two viewControllers, and I thought I had everything set up correctly, but it crashes with no error printed when I perform the segue...

Here's what I've done:

In the DESTINATION viewController, we'll call it VC1 (bottom of the stack) I created this action:

```
@IBAction func unwind(segue:UIStoryboardSegue){}
```

In the interface builder I hooked up VC3 (the third view controller up) to the unwind segue via the exit button and named it "unwind".

I call perform for segue like so:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwind", sender: self)
```

Here is the view controllers and segue identifier

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Fgy1.jpg

The "Delete Trip" button calls the segue AFTER all the other logic has been taken care of.

As soon as that is called, my app crashes with no error message and shows me the AppDelegate screen. What's going on?

Comment: This kind of crashes mainly caused by wrong identifiers. Are you sure you are using right identifier?

Comment: Also are you doing anything on prepareForSegue?

Comment: The identifier is "unwind" in the storyboard too. No, nothing in prepareForSegue.

Comment: I guess that if you print something in your unwind segue function it doesn't show up in the console?

Comment: Maybe a storyboard screenshot could help.

Comment: Try to change identifiers name to something else also change the IBAction name to something different from your identifier

Comment: If I put a print statement in the segue function it DOES show up. I have included a screenshot. I need it to go from the third view controller to the first.

Comment: I don't feel like the "action" is the good one, you should have your func name, meaning something like "unwind:" instead of "unwindWithSegue:".

Comment: When you hook VC3 to its exit button, don't you seen "unwind:" proposed in the unwind segues?

Comment: That seemed odd to me too, but no. It automatically appends "WithSegue" to whatever I name that function. "unwindWithSegue:" is the only option that shows up.

Comment: Maybe you should try what @Mohammadalijf suggested you: rename your unwind function and your segue identifier (try func unwindToVC1(segue:UIStoryboardSegue){} and "unwindToFirst" as segue identifier) and see what happens.

Comment: I have remade both several times, nothing different happens...

Comment: Do you have an exception breakpoint active?  What do you get if you press the |> "continue" debugger button after your app stops?

Comment: No breakpoints were active. Nothing happens when I press the |> continue button...

Answer (score -1):

If you pushed your VC, you could use:

```
navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Comment: I need to go back _two_ viewControllers. Dismissing only goes back one.

Comment: Right, I read too fast. But if you pushed your VC, you can use navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true).

Comment: Sorry it didn't help.

Answer (score -1):

If you have two VC's presented modally, then you will need to dismiss two VC's modally. Use:
`dismiss(..., completion: { 
   dismiss(..., completion: nil)`

Your current "unwind" segue is simply presenting the original one again..and maybe you don't have identifiers set up correctly or you are overlooking your view hierarchy.

Comment: Unwinding does not "just present the original one again". That would be the same as just segueing to the root controller again.